# How can we add a element at multiple index of a list without using loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, addition

I created a list like this:

> n = [0,0,0,0,0]

now I want to add [100] at index [1,2,3].
so list will become like this -

> n = [0,100,100,100,0]

another example: adding[200] at index [3,4], list will become-

> n = [0,100,100,300,200]

We can do this by using loops, but using loops it will take O(n) time.
I want to know can we add a value at multiple index of a list without using loops?

Comment: Unless you use a specialised data structure (and I'm not sure I know of one with suitable characteristics), modifying _k_ different elements in a list will be O(_k_) at best, no matter the method you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use can `numpy` (known for his performant code) arrays, the synta is easy

```
import numpy as np

n = np.zeros(5) # make array of float, use 'np.zeros(5).astype(int)' for int
n[1:4] = 100
n[3:5] += 200
```

If you print the between each step

```
[  0   0   0   0   0]
[  0 100 100 100   0]
[  0 100 100 300 200]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a list and a list of pairs of indexes and values you want to add on those indexes, you can achieve this the following way

```py
lst = [0] * 10
values = [(3, 100), (5, 200), (7, 300)]

for index, value in values:
     lst[index] = value

print(lst)  # [0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 200, 0, 300, 0, 0]
```

In general, you have to iterate over the indexes you want to use, so it cannot be better than this - O(m), where m is the number of indexes.

Comment: When answering a problem, it's recommended to use the OP's values, not other values